# On completion of allOf Future want to run another loop of future in async

Tags: java-8, completable-future

```
 CompletableFuture.allOf(saveVirtualGeoDataCompletable).thenRun(() -> {
            final AtomicInteger j = new AtomicInteger(0);
            allBuildings.stream().forEach(building -> {
                final List<GenericFloor> floors = building.getFloors();
                if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(floors)) {
                    floors.stream().forEach(floor -> {
                        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(floor.getAreas())) {
                            floor.getAreas().forEach(area -> {
                                 CompletableFuture.runAsync(
                                        () -> persistData(area, floor.toIdentity(), principal),
                                        configDataTaskExecutor);

                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

How to achive runAsync inside RunAsync. I want to wait till the allOf first group futures gets completed and then executed new set of futures

Comment: Why are you creating an entirely unused `AtomicInteger`? Why are you using `CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(…)`; is it really possible that the collections are `null`? Why are you using `stream().forEach(…)` instead of just `forEach(…)`? Besides those points, in which regard does this code not do what you want?

Comment: I wanted to do it sequentially ..... using the future but as it was async it was running in parallel. Using non blocking thread I have certain task to be run in sequence and on completion want async of another collection of task

Comment: The action you’ve passed to `CompletableFuture.allOf(saveVirtualGeoDataCompletable).thenRun(…)` will only run when all futures passed to `allOf` have been completed. What else do you want?

Comment: That's not happening. in here

Comment: So what is happening then?

Comment: All the futures are running in parallel

Comment: So are you saying that the runnable you’ve passed to `thenRun` is executed when the futures passed to `allOf` are not completed?